# Facebook Graph returns a different value than is saved using passport-facebook

Tags: facebook, node.js, facebook-graph-api, passport-facebook

I have an application where the user logs in using facebook account, saving the id, name and email. I'm using https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

```
    UserSchema.statics.findOrCreateFaceBookUser = function(profile, done) {
    var User = this;
    User.findOne({
        'email': profile.emails[0].value
    }, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        if (user) {
            user.facebook = {
                id: profile.id,
                email: profile.emails[0].value,
                name: profile.displayName
            };
            user.save(function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                } else {
                   // done(null, user);
                }
            });
            done(null, user);
        } else {
            User.findOne({
                'facebook.id': profile.id
            }, function(err, user) {
                if (err) {
                    throw err;
                }
                //if (err) return done(err);
                if (user) {
                    done(null, user);
                } else {
                    User.create({
                        firstName:profile.name.givenName,
                        lastName:profile.name.familyName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        gender:profile.gender,
                        image:"http://graph.facebook.com/"+profile.id+"/picture?type=normal",
                        facebook: {
                            id: profile.id,
                            email: profile.emails[0].value,
                            name: profile.displayName
                        }
                    }, function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            throw err;
                        }
                        done(null, user);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

    });
```

The problem is that I need to fetch facebook friends who are also using the application, but the "id" returned by facebook graph does not match what I'm persisting in the application.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=id,name&access_token=xpto

The "profile.id" received the passport-facebook is different from the facebook graph field "id"

Comment: What do you mean by 'a different value than is saved'?  Where are you saving it? what value is different?

Comment: The "id" (facebook userId) is different

Comment: Different to what? what are you comparing it to? Your app will always get the same identifier for a given user, but you won't get the same identifier that a different app gets

Comment: The id that you are getting are most likely an app scoped user id. as @lgy ask the question is where did you get the other ids from?

Comment: Yes, we all understood that. The question was where the "the facebook graph field "id"" you're comparing it with comes from. Graph API Explorer? If so I guess you're using it with the v1.0 of the Graph API, and your app is using v2.0.

Comment: Sorry my english, you are correct, I found the solution in https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#upgrading_v2_0_user_ids